# text file creating with 5th line of each article

Tags: python

I want to create a text file with the 5th line of each of the 32 articles in my text file called `"Aberdeen2005.txt"`. I have already separate the articles of my file using:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):        
           sections.append("".join(current))
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))
```

In order to do so I am trying the following code:

```
for i in range(1,500):
    print(sections[i].readline(5))
```

But it is not working. Any ideas?

Kind regards!

Comment: do you want just the 5th line or up to the fifth line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first when you do `range(1,500)` this might be out of range of the sections raising an `IndexError`, it would be safer to use `range(len(sections))` so that it is always the right size.

it may be more beneficial to keep `current` as a list since it is already split up by line anyway:

```
sections.append(current)
```

then just change `.readline(5)` to `[4]` to get the 4th element from the list (since indices start at 0 so idx 4 is line 5)  so it would look like this:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):        
           sections.append(current) #remove the "".join() to keep it split up by line
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))

for i in range(len(sections)): #range(len(...))
    print(sections[i][4])  #changed .readline(5) to [4] since .readline() only works on files
```

the reason you were running into problems is because `.readline()` is a method on file objects where as by the time it is processed into the lists it is a string raising an `AttributeError` since `str` doesn't have a `.readline` method, instead you can split it up by lines with:

```
sections[i].split("\n")[4]
```

"\n" is the newline character, it may not appear at the end of each line depending on OS or other operations (like if you `.strip()` eachline) but then the sections would just contain strings which may be more to your liking:

```
import re 
sections = [] 
current = []
with open("Aberdeen2005.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r"(?i)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS", line):        
           sections.append("".join(current))
           current = [line]
        else:
           current.append(line)

print(len(sections))

for i in range(len(sections)): #range(len(...))
    print(sections[i].split("\n")[4])  #changed .readline(5) to .split("\n")[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure I'm fully getting what you're going for.
Is it something like this?

```
for a in sections:
    for i, line in enumerate(a):
        if i==4:
            #5th line
            print line
```

Comment: `a in sections` would give characters not lines since they are being joined before added to sections

Comment: also given the fact that `print` is written with brackets in the question it is likely they are using python 3 which raises a syntax error from `print line`